# WCF Service + ASP .NET MVC application. Session expires after callback from the service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, session, callback, null

I have a following issue regarding using WCF service from my ASP .NET mvc application. Service requires a callback method to be implemented on the client side. For that I am using wsDualHttpBinding. Callbacks are being invoked and the correct info is recieved (checked using brakepoints multiple times).

The issue lies in the fact that I'm not able to save the data that I recieve when callback "SendComment" is invoked from WCF service. Callback method definition:

```
public void SendComment(ChatComment cc) 
{ 
    Session["Message"] = cc; 
}
```

This is a method that should allow client (in asp .net) to recieve chat messages that are broadcasted to multiple clients from WCF service.

When I try to access Session["Message"] from the controller methods, it's value is null after I have recieved a callback. This is the main problem. I have to find a way to save the value for it to be available in current session context.

Additionally i can't access any of the other session variables I have saved right before the callback is invoked. They are always null.

Besides how do I know when I've recieved the callback? Do I have to use event handlers or somehow call the controller/view from this method?

I've already tried googling for the answer but none of the solutions explicitly state how to access the value after callback has happened.

P.S. Sessions are set to required in WCF Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work the way you designed it. A few reasons why not:

1. You cannot access session from callback.
2. You cannot call client directly from ASP.Net MVC application.

You have too look for some other solution. I suggest you look into SignalR or if you need something simpler use DB to store data and pool from client.